# What does "He reminded me of me on the sidelines" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Brennan, 69, has stayed ambivalent about Kavanaugh’s nomination.
>
> “Obviously, I’m so disappointed in everyone in this whole process,” he
>   said, adding that alleged victim Dr. Christine Blasey Ford has been
>   the only one who has come out looking good. He did add with a chuckle:
>   “Man, how about how he lost his mind the other night. **He reminded me
>   of me on the sidelines**.”

Can someone help me to understand what Brennan meant by "*He reminded me
of me on the sidelines*" in this context?

I'm also not sure what his stance is by saying "*Obviously, I’m so disappointed in everyone in this whole process,*". What's this "everyone" referring to?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/meet-coach-kept-brett-kavanaugh-court-194547129.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Brennan was the Yale basketball coach when Kavanaugh was a student there.

Even the author writes that he is being "ambivalent" (uncertain) about what his stance is. So we don't really know who "everyone" is. He could be referring to certain side, but he doesn't state it clearly.

---

> Man, how about how he lost his mind the other night. He reminded me of me on the sidelines.

This can be rephrased to:

> **Wow, remember how *Kavanaugh* became very upset the other night. *Kavanaugh* reminded *Brennan* of when *Brennan* [was a coach] on the sidelines [of the basketball court].**

Brennan is just comparing Kavanaugh's behavior to Brennan's behavior as a basketball coach who we can assume was the typically upset and yelling furiously kind.

Comment: when is "the other night"?

Comment: This article is from today, and the hearing was 3 days ago. So he is most likely referring to then. Kavanaugh was upset, yelling, etc. during the hearing. You can see it in his opening statement.